# What is the correct way to select unique values for a single attribute out of a Javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Suppose I have the following JavaScript array of objects:

```
var oData = [
    {field1 : "root", field2: "qqqqq", field3: "aaaaa", field4: "zzzzz"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "qqqqq", field3: "aaaaa", field4: "xxxxx"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "qqqqq", field3: "sssss", field4: "ccccc"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "wwwww", field3: "sssss", field4: "vvvvv"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "wwwww", field3: "ddddd", field4: "bbbbb"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "wwwww", field3: "ddddd", field4: "nnnnn"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "wwwww", field3: "fffff", field4: "mmmmm"}
];
```

What would be the best performing way to

1. copy a single attribute (`field1`, `field2`, `field3`, etc.) of this array to a new array, and
2. this resulting array will only contain a list with distinct values

I.e. the resulting arrays will be

```
var oField1 = [
    {field1 : "root"}
]

var oField2 = [
    {field2 : "qqqqq"},
    {field2 : "wwwww"}
]

var oField3 = [
    {field3 : "aaaaa"},
    {field3 : "sssss"},
    {field3 : "ddddd"},
    {field3 : "fffff"}
]
```

(I have added the three examples just to show what I try to achieve. If I can do it for one attribute, I can of course do it for all ;-) )

I can loop through the array, and push only the unique values to the new arrays, or I can clone the array, remove the unneeded attributes and slice to make unique, but these methods feel kinda 'dirty'

Is there an elegant yet good-performing way to achieve the above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I can loop through the array, and push only the unique values to the new arrays" -- do that.

Comment: The reason I won't do that at first is, it would take more lines of code and thus seems a bit like a dirty solution. I was more looking for something clean and elegant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jquery:

```
$.unique(oData.map(function(x) { return x.field1; }))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
user Underscore js

var oData = [
    {field1 : "root", field2: "qqqqq", field3: "aaaaa", field4: "zzzzz"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "qqqqq", field3: "aaaaa", field4: "xxxxx"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "qqqqq", field3: "sssss", field4: "ccccc"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "wwwww", field3: "sssss", field4: "vvvvv"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "wwwww", field3: "ddddd", field4: "bbbbb"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "wwwww", field3: "ddddd", field4: "nnnnn"},
    {field1 : "root", field2: "wwwww", field3: "fffff", field4: "mmmmm"}
];

var field2distinct =  _.uniq(_.pluck(oData,'field2'));
```

http://jsbin.com/fivis/1/edit?html,css,js,output

using jquery

$.unique(oData.map(function(x) { return x.field1; }));

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I don't use UnderscoreJS at this project. Your solution certainly works too, hence my upvote.